# Minimum team size & project duration (in Man-hours) for Scrum?

Tags: project, scrum

What would you say is the minimum / appropriate team size and project duration for using Scrum?

We're thinking about using Scrum for our next software project (about 1600 - 1800 Man-hours) with a team size of 7 members. Since the team size is pretty big (in relation to the project duration, but cant avoid that), would you prefer Scrum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7 members in a team is perfect from SCRUM. The only reasons why you would consider some other process instead of SCRUM:

- Your requirements change radically on a daily basis.
- Your project is shorter than 1 week.
- Members of your team are not willing to adapt to the SCRUM way of doing things.
- All your members are senior software developers and know exactly what must be done. Then trust me, SCRUM is a waste of time.

Finally, in SCRUM you first experiment little bit in order to find the perfect balance. (That comes from SCRUM being empirical process)

Comment: Even having project with just senior software developers, you will benefit Scrum way of doing things if you want to effectively prioritize your tasks by Product Owner. Scrum also helps team to have shippable product at the end of every Sprint. The team can then have demo for product owner which helps the owner to further prioritize what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, 5 members and 1 week sprint is an absolute minimum.

Scrum Master, Product Owner, 2 Developers and 1 Tester. If you have less people - you just don't need SCRUM.

7 members is not very big, we had even more.

Answer (score 1):

According to Winston Royce (publisher of the original Waterfall paper in 1970), the **waterfall** methodology should be used only for - and I quote - the *most simple and straightforward projects* (this is a true and sad anecdote: Waterfall was meant as an example of how *not* to do things).

I would therefore say that for short, simple and straightforward projects, the kind that the team can complete in one sprint (usually 1-4 weeks), you **may** use another methodology, as you will not be gaining any advantage from the feedback cycles, and will generally have no opportunity to inspect and adapt you process.

As for the size of the team, I think that any size that can be managed is good. The project scope will dictate how many people are required in order to complete it in one sprint.